# How can I install pflogsumm for Postfix mail log analyzer?

Tags: installation, server, mail, postfix

I am useing Postfix mail server in Ubuntu 13.04. I want to install pflogsumm in my server and analyze the mail log. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

to install pflogsumm  in your Ubuntu,  open your terminal with CTRL+ALT+T and type as

```
sudo apt-get install pflogsumm
```

Configuration:

We want pflogsumm to be run by a cron job each day and send the report to `postmaster@example.com`. Therefore we must configure our system that it writes one mail log file for 24 hours, and afterwards starts the next mail log so that we can feed the old mail log to pflogsumm. Therefore we configure logrotate (that's the program that rotates our system's log files) like this: open `/etc/logrotate.conf` and append the following stanza to it, after the line # system-specific logs may be configured here:

in terminal do as

```
sudo -i

nano /etc/logrotate.conf
```

then

```
/var/log/mail.log {
    missingok
    daily
    rotate 7
    create
    compress
    start 0
}
```

There's a logrotate script in `/etc/cron.daily`. This script is called everyday between 06:00h and 07:00h. With the configuration we just made, it will copy the current Postfix log `/var/log/mail.log` to `/var/log/mail.log.0` and compress it, and the compressed file will be `/var/log/mail.log.0.gz`. It will also create a new, empty `/var/log/mail.log` to which Postfix can log for the next 24 hours.

Now we create the script `/usr/local/sbin/postfix_report.sh` which invokes pflogsumm and makes it send the report to postmaster@example.com:

```
nano /usr/local/sbin/postfix_report.sh
```

script as

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
gunzip /var/log/mail.log.0.gz

pflogsumm /var/log/mail.log.0 | formail -c -I"Subject: Mail Statistics" -I"From: pflogsumm@localhost" -I"To: postmaster@example.com" -I"Received: from www.example.com ([192.168.0.100])" | sendmail postmaster@example.com

gzip /var/log/mail.log.0
exit 0
```

We must make this script executable:

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/sbin/postfix_report.sh
```

Then we create a cron job which calls the script everyday at 07:00h:

```
crontab -e
```

then

```
 0 7 * * * /usr/local/sbin/postfix_report.sh &> /dev/null
```

This will send the report to postmaster@example.com. It looks like this in an email client:

[image]

For more information & must read : [click here](http://www.howtoforge.com/mail_statistics_mailgraph_pflogsumm)

Comment: There are a few things missing here that are very important or this won't work (at all). First of all, you need to open up the logrotate for rsyslog ``nano /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`` and comment out the mail.log entry ``#/var/log/mail.log``. Otherwise, there will be two (and conflicting) entries for mail.log in logrotate. Secondly, after doing so, you need to restart the logrotate service ``systemctl restart logrotate``.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to mess with any of that. See my answer for a much easier approach.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of cron.daily for a daily report, or run a one-liner:

`sudo apt install pflogsumm`

`sudo nano /etc/cron.daily/pflogsumm`

Add this / suit to your needs:

```
#!/bin/sh
test -x /usr/sbin/pflogsumm || exit 0

/usr/sbin/pflogsumm -d yesterday --problems_first /var/log/mail.lo* \
| mail -a 'From: Daily Postfix Report <no_reply@example.net>' -s "EXAMPLE.NET Email Server - Daily Activity Report" postmaster@example.net
```

That's all you need. **Done.**

But, be sure to test it:

Execute the cron.daily script you made above:
`sudo /etc/cron.daily/pflogsumm`

or, you can test it using same line under the root account:

```
sudo su # become root

/usr/sbin/pflogsumm -d yesterday --problems_first /var/log/mail.lo* | mail -a 'From: Daily Postfix Report <no_reply@example.net>' -s "EXAMPLE.NET Email Server - Daily Activity Report" postmaster@example.net
```

You should immediately receive an email giving the results.

**This will be followed *daily* by a similar email displaying "yesterdays" results.**

*There is no reason to do anything fancier than simply using cron.daily as per above - unless you have numerous and/or big log files, or want something other than daily stats.*

References:

- https://linux.die.net/man/1/pflogsumm
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/pflogsumm

---

**Note: Future versions of Ubuntu** (see [Debian 12/Bookworm](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#changes-to-system-logging) as of this writing) will (probably) have the mail log going strictly to `journalctl` (systemd journal) and Rsyslog will no longer be installed by default. You would just substitute `/var/log/mail.lo*` above for something like:
`journalctl --no-pager -a -u postfix@-.service`

You could optionally just install rsyslog and edit the config so mail.log goes to /var/log/ as in the past. Be sure to add the new mail.log to logrotate as well if you do.

References:

- https://wiki.debian.org/Rsyslog
- https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#changes-to-system-logging